# How to update the Look up field

Tags: trigger

We have one requirement we wants to be update Lookup field.

Let say we have a one Object called `"Project_Task" (TASKRAY__Project_Task__c)`. In the same object we have lookup field called as `"Project"(TASKRAY__Project__c)`.This field is Lookup to(TaskRay Project).Whenever we are `select  Support Request Team = AE Suport Request, TASKRAY__Project__c(LookupField)` should be update "AE NA" Based on Pole Field (User Object) Means (if pole = AE NA ).

here `TASKRAY__Project_Task__c(Child),TASKRAY__Project__c(Master).`

Please Find the Below trigger which we are tried please update where we made the mistakes.

```
Trigger TaskRayUpdate on  TASKRAY__Project_Task__c(before insert,before update){  
list<TASKRAY__Project__c> Tasklist=new List<TASKRAY__Project__c>();
for(TASKRAY__Project_Task__c  t : Trigger.new){
 if(t.Type_of_Request__c == 'Support Request'){         
         if(t.createdby.Pole__c == 'North America')            
             t.TASKRAY__Project__c = '18 digit id';            
         else if(t.createdby.Pole__c == 'China')
             t.TASKRAY__Project__c = 'AE China';
         else if(t.createdby.Pole__c == 'APAC')
             t.TASKRAY__Project__c = 'AE APAC';
         else if(t.createdby.Pole__c == 'EMEA')
             t.TASKRAY__Project__c = 'AE EMEA';
         else if(t.createdby.Pole__c == 'LATAM')
             t.TASKRAY__Project__c = 'AE LATAM';
         }
    }
 update Tasklist;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a map here.

Also I would suggest to use List CustomSetting, or CustomMetadata or a map to store the matching pairs.

Below I show example of how Map can be used to store the matching pairs.

```
Trigger TaskRayUpdate on  TASKRAY__Project_Task__c(before insert,before update){  
    Map<String, String> matchingPairsMap = new Map<String, String>{
        'North America' => 'AE NA',
         'China' => 'AE China',
         'APAC' => 'AE APAC',
         'EMEA' => 'AE EMEA',
         'LATAM' => 'AE LATAM'
    };
    Map<String, TASKRAY__Project__c> projectsMap = new Map<String, TASKRAY__Project__c>();
    for ( TASKRAY__Project__c p: [ SELECT Id, Name FROM TASKRAY__Project__c WHERE Name IN :matchingPairsMap.values()] ) {
        projectsMap.put( p.Name, p );
    }
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(TASKRAY__Project_Task__c  t : Trigger.new){
        userIds.add(t.OwnerId);
    }

    Map<Id, User> usersMap = new Map<Id, User>([ SELECT Id, Pole__c FROM User WHERE Id IN: userIds ]);
    for(TASKRAY__Project_Task__c  t : Trigger.new){
        if(t.Type_of_Request__c == 'Support Request'){         
            User u = usersMap.get( t.OwnerId );
            String pole = u.Pole__c;
            if( !String.isBlank( pole ) && matchingPairsMap.keySet().contains( pole ) ) {
                TASKRAY__Project__c p = projectsMap.get( matchingPairsMap.get( pole ) );
                if ( p != null )
                    t.TASKRAY__Project__c = p.Id;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Patlatus,   Thanks for your reply,   I have updated your logic in my trigger but still not working. Can you please check one more time  Thanks

Comment: Could you please be more precise what exactly is not working? What result do you expect? What do you get? Which are the case conditions?

Comment: Project field is not updating. Whenever we can select  Support request = "Support request" Project field should be update Like "AE NA,AE EMEA".  I have tried your logic which are mentioned above  but not working , and also we  made some changes in the map showing error like this "Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Id].values() at line 9 column 63.Please find below code which we are tried
"

Comment: Not able to copy entire code.Please find bit of logic:Map<String,ID> projectsMap = new Map<String,ID>();if(t.createdby.Pole__c == 'North America')            
t.TASKRAY__Project__c = projectsMap.get('AE NA').values();

Comment: I thought you are trying to populate lookup field on TASKRAY__Project_Task__c. Are you saying that you are trying to populate some field on related project TASKRAY__Project__c? Which field do you want to populate and with which value?

Comment: ,Yes,you are correct,We are trying to populate lookup field on TASKRAY__Project_Task__c. We have one field that is Lookup field "Project(TASKRAY__Project__c)" We are trying to update that field as mentioned below scenario.

Comment: 1.if TaskRay_Task.Support Team Request = AE Support Request
then{if TaskRay_Task.created by. Pole = NA or North America then set TaskRay_Task.project= AE NA or Project id=''  2.if TaskRay_Task.created by. Pole = China then set TaskRay_Task.project= AE China or Project id= '' 3.if TaskRay_Task.created by. Pole = APAC then set TaskRay_Task.project= AE APAC or Project id= '' 4.if TaskRay_Task.created by. Pole = EMEA or MEA then set TaskRay_Task.project= AE EMEA or Project id= '' 5.if TaskRay_Task.created by. Pole = LATAM then set TaskRay_Task.project= AE LATAM or Project id= ''

Comment: Maybe it was not working because of wrong name of project in the first case and also relationship fields are not populated on trigger execution, so you need additional map and query. I have updated my answer, please try again.

Comment: Thanks for your help..we have facing error while saving the record Like "Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger TaskRayUpdate caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: TaskRayUpdate: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.TaskRayUpdate: line 10, column 1"   that is "  if(taskWithAdditionalField.createdby.Pole__c == 'North America')"

Comment: Yes, this makes sense since on insert there is no id on inserted records. I have updated my code, please take a look a my updated answer. Also I updated the code to use map for matching pairs

Comment: ,Still facing  System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.TaskRayUpdate: line 22, column 1    "    String pole = u.Pole__c;" can you please advise how to avoid this one....

Comment: Oops ... Yeah, we just need to update the previous line. I have updated it.

Comment: But Still getting same error Please check this "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.TaskRayUpdate: line 22, column 1"  . Thanks

Comment: @Devi: Are you trying to build a custom managed package or are you trying to build a functionality on a top of managed package? I see prefix in your object names. I have created your data model in one of my sandboxes and tried this trigger. Looks like CreatedById field is not populated on before trigger, we can use OwnerId field (which is populated on before trigger and if you don't change owner it should coincide with createdbyid user ) or after trigger. I changed code to use OwnerId and make additional changes. This version works in my environment.